# How to load parameters with different values based on user role in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a multitude of parameters in `parameters.yml` file, each parameter should have a different value based on logged in user's role.

Is there is way to systematically decide and load correct value based on logged in user's role?

Example:

```
parameters:
    user.address_code
    manager.address_code
```

Ideally, I don't want to add conditions in my code for `manager` or `user` before I use `address_code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since parameters values are used during the container compilation, **their value cannot be changed at runtime**.

And since the user role can only be known during a request, what you want to do simply cannot be done.

But you are most likely you are approaching the problem from the wrong end.

Just encapsulate the logic in a service of some kind. A simplistic example:

The service:

```php
namespace App\Service;

class FooService
{

    private array $configuration;

    public function __construct(array $configuration)
    {
        $this->configuration = $configuration;
    }

    public function getAddressCodeFor(string $role): string
    {
        return $this->configuration[$role] ?? '';
    }
}
```

Your parameters:

```
# services.yaml
parameters:
    address_code:
        ROLE_USER: 'foo'
        ROLE_ADMIN: 'bar'
```

Configuration to make sure the service know about your parameters:

```
#services.yaml

App\Service\FooService:
    arguments: ['%address_code%']
```

Then it's only a matter of injecting `FooService` wherever you need these values, and call `getAddressCodeFor($role)` where you need it:

```
class FakeController extends AbstractController
{

    private FooService $paramService;

    public function __construct(FooService $service)
    {
        $this->paramService = $service;
    }

    public function someAction(): Response
    {
        $address_code = $this->paramService->getAddressCodeFor('ROLE_ADMIN');

        return $this->json(['address_code' => $address_code]);
    }

}
```

This is just an example, but you can adjust it to follow your needs.

Comment: thank you for your response @yivi, I was also thinking about similar solution just wanted to take community opinion incase I was wrong..